# AWS DyanmoDB Nodejs update array of array

Tags: arrays, node.js, amazon-dynamodb

Trying to update array of array in DynamoDB.

This is the schema, I want the data insert into personalData as item of an array

[image]

This is the params:

```
var params = {
  TableName: "coupons",
  Key: {
    'clientId': 'A0002'
  },
  ReturnValues: 'ALL_NEW',
  UpdateExpression: 'set #att = list_append(if_not_exists(#att, :empty_list), :data)',
  ExpressionAttributeNames: {
    '#att': 'campaigns.personalData'
  },
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ':data': [{
      couponCode: "S0001",
      regDate: "20170728"
    }],
    ':empty_list': []
  }
}
```

But after the code ran, it created a new attribute 'campaigns.personalData', not insert into the original personalData array:

[image]

Comment: I think instead of using a single variable `#att` for `campaigns.personalData`, you need to use 2 of them like `#att.#subatt`, and define them like:
`{ '#att': 'campaigns',
'#subatt': 'personalData' }`

Comment: Thanks, tried your approach, but no luck
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
      '#att': 'campaigns',
      '#subatt': 'personalData'
    },

and got another error msg:
{ ValidationException: The document path provided in the update expression is invalid for update

Comment: you are accessing campaigns.personalData but campaigns is a list and you are accessing personalData with a dot operator.So personalData is a property of a map that is present on 0 index of the campaigns list